# Jackson serialize POJO to JS Object

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

```
class Foo {
  String name = "Bar";
}
```

Serialising the above object using `ObjectMapper().convertValue(foo, JsonNode::class)` will return JSON object as:

```
{
  "name": "Bar"
}
```

my desired result however is:

```
{
  name: "Bar"
}
```

I have tried a custom serialiser but it always writes keys as strings. Is there a way to serialise my POJO in this format using Jackson or any of it's annotation to avoid a substituting chars or building the string my self.

Comment: So is the definition of JSON: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation 
How to parse this can be read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Your desired result isn't valid JSON.  Are you attempting to produce JSON, or something JSON-like?

Comment: @Makoto JSON-like as JavaScript object.

Comment: Remember - you can't have a JavaScript object with invalid JSON, so I'll state it once more - is this going to be something which is JSON-like (and you deal with the fact that it isn't valid on your side), or are you feeding this to something else (like a JavaScript app) which would reasonably expect valid JSON?

Comment: I generate this as a javascript object and pass it  using `application/javascript` content type. This is injected  in JS frontend app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the fact that your "JSON" will not be valid anymore you can disable `JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES` in your `ObjectMapper`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .disable(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES);
```

The result of `mapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo())` will be:

```
{name:"Bar"}
```

To enable pretty print you can use either:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .disable(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES)
        .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

Or use this in the output step:

```
String result = mapper
        .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(new Foo());
```

The result in both cases will be:

```
{
  name : "Bar"
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for I'm aware it breaks JSON validity but it's not exactly going to be JSON it's injected on frontend as JS Object which can have non-quoted field names. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry it works it was loading response from cache. Thanks for the help.